# Aws Lambda: Python function with Pandas dependency

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to deploy to python function which has the dependency on external libraries?
For example, I am trying to deploy to a data-analysis python function. When I try to test the python function from the lambda console, I get:

`Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named pandas`

> I am totally new to Aws Lambda

Is there a linux box on which Lambda functions run where I can install these libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to install `pandas` using `pip install pandas` ? It seems that pandas package/module isn't installed in your box.

Comment: @ChihebNexus What do you mean by my box? Sorry but I do not know where lambda functions run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a deployment package as detailed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#deployment-pkg-for-virtualenv

This just means bundling the contents of site-packages for the environment you're developing on into the deployment package together with the lambda python script into a zip that is uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

If you new to Lambda deployment, you might want [check this tutorial](https://medium.com/the-python-backend/hassle-free-python-lambda-deployment-tutorial-script-9c65bcf47e26) (I wrote), which covers the most common pitfalls. And gives you a script as well to automate the entire process.